# Joomla 3 Newsflash layout override

Tags: module, overrides

Im using Joomla 3 and need to add a custom layout override for the Newsflash module.

I know the file structure needed to do a layout override but I can't find the folder that has the layouts for the Newsflash module.

Can anyone tell me where to find the Newsflash folder? Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to override the files in `modules/mod_articles_news/tmpl`.

Copy the files you want to override to `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_articles_news/`.

The following files can be overridden:

- `_item.php` - this is where each item is generated. This file is called by the other files using `JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath()`
- `default.php` - the default module layout.
- `horizontal.php` - alternative layout (horizontal...)
- `vertical.php` - alternative layout (vertical...)

[image: Alternative layout]